# How to get "Lodging" with Google My Business?

Tags: google-my-business-api

I want to get the Attributes of a Lodging in Google My Business.
Looking at this Google My Business Reference, I tried to access it as follows.

【Reference】
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/lodging/rest/v1/locations/getLodging

【Request】
https://mybusinesslodging.googleapis.com/v1/locations/xxx/lodging?readMask=*
↑{locationId} is entered in xxx

The Response is a 404. I don't know why.
The specified "Locations" are certainly hotels, and Lodging API is also enabled.

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCUC7.jpg)

Comment: Hi @piyoen did you manage to solve this?